# how to use re to match a pattern and keep pattern in python

Tags: python, python-re

I have a bunch of string in a list like this:
['2000-01-01', '2000-22-01', '02000-2-2'...]

I would like to transform all elements into this ['2000-01-1', '2000-22-1', '2000-02-2']
that's say [no zero padding]-[zero padding]-[no zero padding]

what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `int` with `zfill`:

```
import re
s = ['2000-01-01', '2000-22-01', '02000-2-2']
new_s = [f'{(k:=i.split("-"))[0]}-{k[1].zfill(2)}-{int(k[-1])}' for i in s]
```

Output:

```
['2000-01-1', '2000-22-1', '02000-02-2']
```

Comment: oh! this answer partly fits my requirement... I would like to pad zero in the middle string... but it is just what I don't understand .... thank you so much~

Comment: @AstikGabani actually this is not date. just a number series

Comment: @Ajax1234 thank you so much! but I prefer to use re. and I have learned how to remove the zero-padding in the last part of string~

Comment: "the walrus operator" works from **python 3.8**, ths solution will not be applicable for python version less than 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

A possible **regex-free** solution:

```
inp = ['2000-01-01', '2000-22-01', '02000-2-2']
outp = []
for date in inp:
  nums = date.split("-")
  nums[0] = nums[0].lstrip("0")
  nums[2] = nums[2].lstrip("0")
  outp.append("-".join(nums))
```

Answer (score 0):

Capture regex groups, then modify them.

```
import re

input_list = ['2000-01-01', '2000-22-01', '02000-2-2']

for some_date in input_list:
    print('\n', some_date)
    the_regex = r'(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)'

    year = re.search(the_regex, some_date).group(1).lstrip('0')  # year
    day = re.search(the_regex, some_date).group(2).zfill(2)      # day
    month = re.search(the_regex, some_date).group(3).lstrip('0') # month
    
    the_output = f'{year}-{day}-{month}'
    print(the_output)
```